# Spring i18n auto set of language

Tags: java, spring, internationalization

I have set up two languages on my site using spring i18n. By default language is X. My goal is found best way to set English language if user come from other country than X .

My spring config:

```
...
@Bean
public LocaleResolver localeResolver(){
  CookieLocaleResolver resolver = new CookieLocaleResolver();
  resolver.setDefaultLocale(new Locale("x"));
  resolver.setCookieName("myLocaleCookie");
  resolver.setCookieMaxAge(4800);
  return resolver;
}

@Override 
  public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
  LocaleChangeInterceptor interceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
  interceptor.setParamName("lng");
  registry.addInterceptor(interceptor);
}
...
```